# Anylogic stopwatch/timer

Tags: timer, anylogic

I'm wondering if there is something in anylogic that's the opposite to an event, this is, an object that counts the lapse of time instead of the time remaining.

Example:

- I have a factory simulation where I want to visualize the amount of time that a specific worker (agent that is a resource) has been working since his shift started --> I could query for a function created in worker which is what I currently do but it would be neater to have a timer with the time worked
- On the other hand I want to account for the busy time of a machine in a way that it's computed life (there's also the option of querying it)

For those two examples an object like an Event that has a counter and functionality around it would be useful if it could be used with increasing time instead of decreasing

I haven't found anything of the sort...

Comment: I think you need to frame this in the context of what you'd want to do with such an object. If you want to measure how much sim-time has elapsed, you just compare the current time() to some stored value. What would you want a 'self-contained object' related to this to do?

Answer (score 0):

The Time Measure Start and Time Measure End blocks in the DES palette did the trick